# Cyanogenmod 10.2 crashes when trying to access storage settings

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb-connection-mode, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have just installed CyanogenMod 10.2-20130727-Unofficial-i9300 and I am facing a problem with connecting to USB on Windows. Windows won't install drivers when I connect to USB (MTP USB device driver) and Android shows an error that says:

> Unfortunately the process android.process.media has stopped.

Also when going to Settings > Storage it crashes the Settings menu. Can you please help me fix this issue?

Comment: The phone won't install drivers? Sure not, there's no need for that. As for the crashes: Could you please [edit] your question and add a few more details on that: any error message displayed? What steps you are performing when it crashes?

Comment: Please also add what build of Cyanogenmod you have: is it a stable release, a release candidate, a beta, or a nightly? If it's a nightly, the solution is probably "install a stable release or a  different nightly that doesn't have this problem".

Comment: I have updated the question!